# How to deal with Dynamic Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, group-by, sql-null

Simple Question

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

I am looking to do is do a select so I can get a result as

[image]

Is this a PIVOTING issue? looking for suggestions to see how I can form a 'Select' query for this?

Comment: All i have tried is 'Select * from table where COALESCE(columnd, columnE) IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to merge rows having the same values in the first three columns, then use aggregation:

```
select columna, columnb,columnc, max(columnd) columnd, max(columne) columne
from mytable
group by columna, columnb, columnc
```

Aggregate functions - such as `max()` - ignore `null` values, so `max(columnd)` gives you the non-`null` value across rows having the same `(columna, columnb,columnc)`.

Comment: Thanks for this..there are other columns too, not sure if we want to do aggregate on the select statement. I have put each column in group by then. right?

Comment: @fireholster: yes, all columns in the `select` clause that are not in an aggregate function (here, `max()`) must be repeated in the `group by` clause.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the Max explanation too.